# Why can integer type int64_t not hold this legal value?

Tags: c++, c++11, int, int64, numeric-limits

I'm trying to write a test case for some corner case. For input of type `int64_t`, the following line won't compile:

```
int64_t a = -9223372036854775808LL;
```

The error/warning is:

```
error: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned [-Werror]
```

I thought the number was out of range, so I tried:

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min() << std::endl;
```

It outputs exactly the same number!!! So the constant is within the range.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may write

```
int64_t a = -1 - 9223372036854775807LL;
```

The problem is that the `-` is not part of the literal, it is unary minus.  So the compiler first sees `9223372036854775808LL` (out of range for signed `int64_t`) and then finds the negative of this.

By applying binary minus, we can use two literals which are each in range.

Answer (score 9):

Ben's already explained the reason, here's two other possible solutions.

Try this

```
int64_t a = INT64_MIN;
```

or this

```
int64_t a = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min();
```